# how can I use built-in ASP.NET templates for sending emails?

Tags: asp.net, templates

Is there any samples on how to use ASP.NET built-in templates out of the page, just for rendering text with params. For instance, to build email message.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you clarify on your question?

Comment: I have email template with replacements "Dear<%User.Name%>, you have create account on <%User.Hostname%>" .etc. Then I just pass params and have string output with replacements. This sample is very trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the class [MailDefinition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.maildefinition.aspx)

[Here](http://dotnettricks.com/blogs/roberhinojosablog/archive/2006/05/12/57.aspx) you have a sample of how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by making an ordinary aspx page be the template then having that page pull out querystring values and use them in the response.  Then you'd just use http://www.systemnetmail.com/faq/4.8.aspx to call the aspx page.